# Creating colour co-ordinated values on map from data in CSV file in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, coordinates, csv

I have a list of values for some data recorded via Magnetic susceptibility, I have these in a shapefile and want to try creating a colour map out of the values.

The values that I'm using relate to, OSGB 1936 / British National Grid, EPSG:27700

Example of the data in CSV file:

[image: example of the data in csv. file]

I want to try to achieve something similar to the coloured area in the second image. I don't know if this will be possible in QGIS but I thought it was worth trying.

[image: example of mag sus data]

Answer (score 3):

QGis should be able to import this directly as an XYZ grid (under Raster) provided it meets the following ([from the GDAL Manual](http://www.gdal.org/frmt_xyz.html)):

- Those datasets are ASCII files with (at least) 3 columns, each line containing the X and Y coordinates of the center of the cell and the value of the cell.
- The spacing between each cell must be constant and no missing value is supported. Cells with same Y coordinates must be placed on consecutive lines. For a same Y coordinate value, the lines in the dataset must be organized by increasing X values. The value of the Y coordinate can increase or decrease however. The supported column separators are space, comma, semicolon and tabulations.

The manual also suggests that you name the columns X, Y & Z for best detection but it might work as you currently have it.

Once imported it will need to be coloured in as with any other raster -> properties->Style.